# WebApi OData property route content negotiation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, nuget-server, asp.net-web-api-odata

I am trying to mimic the behavior of NuGet.org that returns a package Id for an example URL like:

http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Nuget.Core',Version='2.8.3')/Id

This response looks like:

```
<d:Id xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  Nuget.Core
</d:Id>
```

I can create a similar WebApi OData route using [PropertyRoutingConvention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.routing.conventions.propertyroutingconvention.aspx) and creating a method on my controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetId([FromODataUri] string id, [FromODataUri] string version)
{
    var package = Repository.FindPackage(id, new SemanticVersion(version));

    return Ok(package.Id);
}
```

This action is invoked but the response always has Content-Type of application/json:

```
curl -i -q -H 'Accept: application/atom+xml' http://localhost:9001/api/odata/Packages(Id='Nuget.Core',Version='2.8.3')/Id

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; odata=minimalmetadata; streaming=true; charset=utf-8
DataServiceVersion: 3.0

{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:9001/api/odata/$metadata#Edm.String","value":"Nuget.Core"
}
```

In addition to content-negotiation not working, how can I include the property name in the response to make it behave like how NuGet.org behaves?

For sake of clarity, complete code is available at https://github.com/themotleyfool/NuGet.Lucene

Answer (score 0):

Are you mean there is an key-value pair in response? Why not return Ok(package), then the value in response will have

```
"ID":"Nuget.Core"
```